# Extraer una parte de un campo en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Estoy trabajando en una tabla, donde los datos de un campo se almacenan de la siguiente manera:

`Anexo 1|06/04/2020|06/06/2025`

Necesito extraer solamente lo que se encuentra hasta el primer `|` , pero aún no logro conseguirlo. Lo intenté con charindex y un substring, pero la consulta me regresa información a partir del último `|` que encuentra.

¿Cómo puedo realizar esta consulta?

Agrego mi código que tengo:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
 LCD.DATOS,CHARINDEX('|',LCD.DATOS)-10,
 LEN(LCD.Datos)-CHARINDEX('|',LCD.Datos)
FROM Mitabla AS LCD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenes que indicar que vas a iniciar desde `0` (*cero*) hasta la primer ocurrencia de `|`

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(LCD.DATOS, 0, CHARINDEX('|', LCD.DATOS))
FROM Mitabla AS LCD
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23beb076d419eff2bf7de55db3e13361)</kbd>

Comment: Muchas gracias!
El query me ayudo extrayendo la información que necesitaba tener